# $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation is useless?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

I noticed strange thing while trying to unit test one of my controllers with karma. Here is spec:

```
it 'should POST new category data to /api/categories with category name', ->
  $httpBackend.expectGET '/api/categories'
    .respond 200, ''
  $httpBackend.expectPOST '/api/categories', {name: 'food' }
    .respond 201, ''
  scope.name = 'food'
  scope.addCategory()
  $httpBackend.flush()
```

and this is my controller:

```
angular.module 'fmAppApp'
    .controller 'CategoriesCtrl', (Category, $scope) ->
      $scope.categories = Category.query()
      $scope.addCategory = ->
        category = new Category { name: $scope.name}
        category.$save()
        $scope.categories.push category
        $scope.name = ''
```

`Category` dependency above is $resource.

So when I comment the line in controller which performs POST request (`category.$save()`)

I get this error from karma:
`Error: Unsatisfied requests: POST /api/categories`

which I find strange because $httpBackend provides method for this kind of  assertions, namely `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation` right?
[it's described here in angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#verifyNoOutstandingExpectation) it's said

> Verifies that all of the requests defined via the expect api were made. If any of the requests were not made, verifyNoOutstandingExpectation throws an exception.

I see everybody using it, so I also used to put it in `afterEach` but now I don't see the point in it anymore since karma throws error anyway if expected request wasn't made and spec fails.

So is it method useless, or it's something I don't understand?

If I haven't made it clear, I  ***didn't call*** verifyNoOutstandingExpectation and error happens nevertheless.

Comment: Are you sure that you keep getting this error when `verifyNoOutstandingExpectation` isn't set? It should not appear.

Comment: @Mik378 I am 100% sure.

Comment: looks like you right. If you eliminate `$httpBackend.flush()` karma will never show an error. In this case you need `verifyNoOutstandingExpectation`, but in case of using `$httpBackend.fulsh()` you'll get same error.